# Flow upgrade to 0.64 results in bunch of new errors

Tags: react-native, flowtype, expo

I recently upgraded `flow-bin` and `.flowconfig` from `0.53` to `0.64` and now flow is resulting in bunch of new errors inside react-native framework files.

What can I do about this situation?

```
Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/ScrollResponder.js:480
480:       var { animated, ...rect } = rect;
                           ^^^^^^^ rect. This type is incompatible with
472:     rect: { x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number, animated?: boolean },
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type
  Property `animated` is incompatible:
    472:     rect: { x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number, animated?: boolean },
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `animated`. Property not found in
    480:       var { animated, ...rect } = rect;
                               ^^^^^^^ rect

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Inspector/Inspector.js:104
104:       clearTimeout(_hideWait);
                        ^^^^^^^^^ null. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
733: declare function clearTimeout(timeoutId?: TimeoutID): void;
                                               ^^^^^^^^^ TimeoutID. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_213409a3/core.js:733

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Interaction/InteractionManager.js:171
171:       _nextUpdateHandle = setTimeout(_processUpdate, 0 + DEBUG_DELAY);
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TimeoutID. This type is incompatible with
182:   _nextUpdateHandle = 0;
                           ^ number

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js:465
           v--------------------------------
465:       this._virtualizedListPairs.push({
466:         viewabilityConfig: this.props.viewabilityConfig,
467:         onViewableItemsChanged: this._createOnViewableItemsChanged(
...:
470:       });
           -^ rest parameter array of call of method `push`. Has some incompatible type argument with
249:     push(...items: Array<T>): number;
                        ^^^^^^^^ array type. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_213409a3/core.js:249
  Type argument `T` is incompatible:
                                               v
    465:       this._virtualizedListPairs.push({
    466:         viewabilityConfig: this.props.viewabilityConfig,
    467:         onViewableItemsChanged: this._createOnViewableItemsChanged(
    ...:
    470:       });
               ^ object literal. This type is incompatible with
    476:   _virtualizedListPairs: Array<ViewabilityConfigCallbackPair> = [];
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ViewabilityConfigCallbackPair
      Property `viewabilityConfig` is incompatible:
        466:         viewabilityConfig: this.props.viewabilityConfig,
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. Inexact type is incompatible with exact type
         26:   viewabilityConfig: ViewabilityConfig,
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ViewabilityConfig. See: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/ViewabilityHelper.js:26

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js:558
558:       return keyExtractor(items, index);
                               ^^^^^ array type. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
151:   keyExtractor: (item: ItemT, index: number) => string,
                            ^^^^^ ItemT

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/ViewabilityHelper.js:91
 91:     this._timers.forEach(clearTimeout);
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^ function type. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
572:     forEach(callbackfn: (value: T, index: T, set: Set<T>) => mixed, thisArg?: any): void;
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function type. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_213409a3/core.js:572
  The first parameter is incompatible:
     77:   _timers: Set<number> = new Set();
                        ^^^^^^ number. This type is incompatible with
    733: declare function clearTimeout(timeoutId?: TimeoutID): void;
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^ TimeoutID. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_213409a3/core.js:733

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/ViewabilityHelper.js:200
200:         this._timers.delete(handle);
                                 ^^^^^^ TimeoutID. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
 77:   _timers: Set<number> = new Set();
                    ^^^^^^ number

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/ViewabilityHelper.js:207
207:       this._timers.add(handle);
                            ^^^^^^ TimeoutID. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
 77:   _timers: Set<number> = new Set();
                    ^^^^^^ number

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js:484
                                  v
484:           this.scrollToIndex({
485:             animated: false,
486:             index: this.props.initialScrollIndex,
487:           }),
               ^ object literal. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
                             v
266:   scrollToIndex(params: {
267:     animated?: ?boolean,
268:     index: number,
...:
271:   }) {
       ^ object type
  Property `index` is incompatible:
    486:             index: this.props.initialScrollIndex,
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ null or undefined. This type is incompatible with
    268:     index: number,
                    ^^^^^^ number

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js:484
                                  v
484:           this.scrollToIndex({
485:             animated: false,
486:             index: this.props.initialScrollIndex,
487:           }),
               ^ object literal. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
                             v
266:   scrollToIndex(params: {
267:     animated?: ?boolean,
268:     index: number,
...:
271:   }) {
       ^ object type
  Property `index` is incompatible:
    486:             index: this.props.initialScrollIndex,
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. This type is incompatible with
    268:     index: number,
                    ^^^^^^ number

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js:500
500:     clearTimeout(this._initialScrollIndexTimeout);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ number. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
733: declare function clearTimeout(timeoutId?: TimeoutID): void;
                                               ^^^^^^^^^ TimeoutID. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_213409a3/core.js:733

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js:1016
1016:       distanceFromEnd < onEndReachedThreshold * visibleLength &&
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ null or undefined. The operand of an arithmetic operation must be a number.

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js:1016
1016:       distanceFromEnd < onEndReachedThreshold * visibleLength &&
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. The operand of an arithmetic operation must be a number.

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js:1094
1094:         this.props.onEndReachedThreshold * visibleLength / 2;
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ null or undefined. The operand of an arithmetic operation must be a number.

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js:1094
1094:         this.props.onEndReachedThreshold * visibleLength / 2;
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. The operand of an arithmetic operation must be a number.

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js:1170
1170:           distanceFromEnd < onEndReachedThreshold * visibleLength
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ null or undefined. The operand of an arithmetic operation must be a number.

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js:1170
1170:           distanceFromEnd < onEndReachedThreshold * visibleLength
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. The operand of an arithmetic operation must be a number.

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js:1247
1247:     return frame;
                 ^^^^^ object type. This type is incompatible with the expected return type of
            v
1210:   ): ?{
1211:     length: number,
1212:     offset: number,
...:
1215:   } => {
        ^ object type
  Property `inLayout` is incompatible:
                v
    1210:   ): ?{
    1211:     length: number,
    1212:     offset: number,
    ...:
    1215:   } => {
            ^ property `inLayout`. Property not found in
    1247:     return frame;
                     ^^^^^ object type

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedSectionList.js:236
236:       key: keyExtractor(viewable.item, info.index),
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^ null or undefined. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
101:   keyExtractor: (item: Item, index: number) => string,
                                         ^^^^^^ number

Error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/flattenStyle.js:36
 36:     return getStyle(style);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ number. This type is incompatible with the expected return type of
 29: function flattenStyle(style: ?StyleObj): ?Object {
                                               ^^^^^^ object type


Found 30 errors
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

Comment: you could tell it to ignore node_modules

Comment: It's not recommended.

Comment: Where did you read that

Comment: Many places where such advises were given i.e. Flow's GitHub repo etc.